# SQL Server Fulltext search not finding my rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a SQL Server table and I'm trying to make sense of fulltext searching :-)

I have set up a fulltext catalog and a fulltext index on a table `Entry`, which contains among other columns a `VARCHAR(20)` column called `VPN-ID`.

There are about 200'000 rows in that table, and the `VPN-ID` column has values such as:

```
VPN-000-359-90
VPN-000-363-85
VPN-000-362-07
VPN-000-362-91
VPN-000-355-55
VPN-000-368-36
VPN-000-356-90
```

Now I'm trying to find rows in that table with a fulltext enabled search.

When I do

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Entry
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'VPN-000-362-07')
```

everything's fine and dandy and my rows are returned.

When I start searching with a wildcard like this:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Entry
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'VPN-000-362-%')
```

I am getting results and everything seems fine.

**HOWEVER:** when I searching like this:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Entry
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'VPN-000-36%')
```

suddenly I get no results back at all..... even though there are **clearly** rows that match that search criteria...

Any ideas why?? What other "surprises" might fulltext search have in store for me? :-)

*Update:* to create my fulltext catalog I used:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MyCatalog WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

and to create the fulltext index on my table, I used

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
ON dbo.Entry(list of columns)
KEY INDEX PK_Entry
```

I tried to avoid any "oddball" options as much a I could.

**Update #2:** after a bit more investigation, it appears as if SQL Server Fulltext search somehow interprets my dashes inside the strings as separators....

While this query returns nothing:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Entry
WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"VPN-000-362*"')
```

this one does (splitting up the search term on the dashes):

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Entry
WHERE CONTAINS(*, ' "VPN" AND "000" AND "362*"')
```

OK - seems a bit odd that a dash appears to result in a splitting up that somehow doesn't work.....

Comment: could you add the code, which created the fulltext-index/catalog? maybe there are some freakin' options ...

Comment: I think the `-` is just treated as a word breaking character and not used in the search at all. `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"VPN-000-362*"',1033,NULL,0)`

Comment: Though if you change the language parameter one of the `-` gets preserved. `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"VPN-000-362*"',0,NULL,0)`. Strange! Don't know what the rules are here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

which `Language for Word Breaker` do you use? Have you tried `Neutral`?

[image]

EDIT:
in adition you should use `WHERE CONTAINS([Column], '"text*"')`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) for more information on [Prefix Searches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142492.aspx):

> C. Using CONTAINS with
>
> The following example returns all
>   product names with at least one word
>   starting with the prefix chain in the
>   Name column.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "Chain*" ');
GO
```

btw ... similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295266/sql-server-fulltext-search-for-book) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169968/sql-server-fulltext-on-searchkeyword)

Comment: See my create scripts above - I didn't specify anything special at all; as far as I see, SQL Server used "English" for all my languages

Comment: which result do you get, if you change it to `Neutral`?

Comment: Results stay the same - finds OK with `'VPN-000-362-%'`, doesn't find a thing with `'VPN-000-36%'`

Comment: I tried `WHERE CONTAINS(*, ' "VPN-000-36*" ')` but the results are the same - no rows :-( even through they definitely **ARE** rows that match that critieria! Even if I specify the exact column name in the `CONTAINS` (which I wanted to avoid), I still get no results....

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, but why don't you just do this:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Entry
WHERE [VPN-ID] LIKE 'VPN-000-36%'
```

It seems to me that fulltext search is not the right tool for the job. Just use a normal index on that column.

Comment: I want to be able to search on dozens of fields - I don't like the idea of having to search for field 1, then field 2, then field 3 and so forth. Fulltext search can search in the whole fulltext index at once

Comment: and considering performance, a fulltext-index will surpass a like-search