# T-SQL Using CONTAINS predicate with Hyphen

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, contains

Imagine a table (table1) with one column (column1) and one record whose value is 'roll-over'. Then use the following SQL query and you will not get any records.

```
select * from table1 where contains(column1, ' "roll-over" ')
```

Is there a way to escape the hyphen in the search text? So far I have not been successful trying this (I have tried all below escapes with no success).

```
select * from table1 where contains(column1, ' "roll\-over" ')
select * from table1 where contains(column1, ' "roll!-over" ')
select * from table1 where contains(column1, ' "roll[-]over" ')
```

Also, please note that using the LIKE keyword is not possible for my application because I am taking advantage of full-text search indexing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Fulltext search not finding my rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699556/sql-server-fulltext-search-not-finding-my-rows)

Comment: There seems to be something really wrong with this.  Not even this worked: select 1 as Id, 'hello  "roll-over"  world' as SomeText into test

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_SPID ON test(Id);
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON test(SomeText) 
   KEY INDEX ui_SPID 
   WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;

select * from test where contains(SomeText, 'hello')

drop table test
drop fulltext catalog ft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may not be able to do that.  Give this article a read:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/200043/prb-dashes---ignored-in-search-with-sql-full-text-and-msidxs-queries

They suggest searching only alphanumeric values (lame) or using the LIKE Clause (not an option for you).

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution: you can force the query to return records containing hyphens (or any character) by using the `charindex` function to test that the string contains the character, e.g.:

```
select * from table1 where contains(column1, ' "roll-over" ')
and charindex('-', column1) > 0
```