# SQL Server Full Text Search Doesn't Return Values For Duplicate Words

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm running into a scenario where my full text search with predicate isn't returning results when there are duplicate words one after the other and there is a whitespace between them.

For example, when I search using predicate "other*"... It will not return records which contain "other other". But interestingly, it will return records containing "otherother".

I can't pin point what I'm missing here, why is the whitespace causing the issue?

Here is my SQL query for reference.

```
SELECT p.*, KEY_TBL.RANK  
FROM dbo.Person AS p WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (dbo.Person, PersonFullName, @QueryPredicate, LANGUAGE N'English', @RowCount) AS KEY_TBL ON p.PersonId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `@QueryPredicate`?

Comment: Side point: ["Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: "other*"... with the quotes.... So if you want it escaped, "\"other*\""

Comment: Wondering: does it return rows with only one `other`?

Comment: I just tried it... It didn't return results... I tried to change the language to "Neutral" as proposed here, but no luck.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5699777/1234374

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research I found that other duplicate words like "Xor Xor" where returning results giving a hint maybe the root cause is something different... and it was!

In my case, the FullText Index was created with **STOPLIST = SYSTEM**. So common words like 'Other' or 'He' are skipped by the query, hence the issue.

Now since I'm searching for names, I don't need stoplist all together. If you are in the same situation, turn off the stoplist by running the query below against your table

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON Person SET STOPLIST OFF
```